# Make an unread message count in realtime

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

im doing a chat application using pubnub sdk, my application has the flow like this:
First, when userA logs into the chat application, the application will get conversations based on userA's id, then when userA clicks on a conversation, the application will fetch api to retrieve messages of that conversation based on conversationId, and pubnub will register event listeners and subscribe to a channel, then it can send realtime messages. Currently I want when userA sends a message to userB, if userB has not subscribed to the same channel as userA, then userB has not read the message. UserA and userB both subscribe to the same channel. And then if userB subscribes to the same channel as userA, it will be counted as having read the message, but currently I don't know how to implement the function of counting unread messages to display on the UI in realtime, please help me. This is my entire database, in the server side i'm using Expressjs, prisma orm and mySql, in client side using Reactjs, :

```
model User {
  id            String         @id @default(uuid())
  email         String         @unique
  name          String?
  password      String
  createdAt     DateTime       @default(now())
  conversations Conversation[]
  messages      Message[]
  participants  Participant[]
}

model Conversation {
  id               String        @id @default(uuid())
  conversationName String?
  type             String        @default("1vs1")
  creatorUserId    String
  creatorUser      User          @relation(fields: [creatorUserId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  timestamp        DateTime      @default(now())
  messages         Message[]
  participants     Participant[]
}

model Message {
  id             String        @id @default(uuid())
  conversationId String
  conversation   Conversation  @relation(fields: [conversationId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  senderUserId   String
  senderUser     User          @relation(fields: [senderUserId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  content        String?
  messageType    String
  fileUrl        String?
  emojiCode      String?
  timestamp      DateTime      @default(now())
  isRead         Boolean       @default(false)
}

model Participant {
  id                String       @id @default(uuid())
  conversationId    String
  conversation      Conversation @relation(fields: [conversationId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  userId            String
  user              User         @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

this is my Chat component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Conversation from "../Conversation";
import { conversationAPIs } from '../../apis/conversationAPI';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar';
import { ChatArea } from "../ChatArea";

function Chat() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const [ conversations, setConversations ] = useState([]);
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null);
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
    const [ selectedConversationId, setSelectedConversationId ] = useState(null);
    const [ selectedParticipantInfo, setSelectedParticipantInfo ] = useState(null);
    const [ searchQuery, setSearchQuery ] = useState("");

    const filteredConversations = conversations.filter(convo =>
        convo.participantInfo?.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!user || !user.id) return;
        const fetchConversations = async () => {
            try
            {
                const response = await conversationAPIs.getConversationsForUser(user.id);
                setConversations(response.data.conversations);
            } catch (error)
            {
                setError(error);
            } finally
            {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };
        fetchConversations();
    }, [ user.id ]);

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error: { error.message }</p>;

    const handleConversationClick = (conversationId, participantInfo) => {
        setSelectedConversationId(conversationId);
        setSelectedParticipantInfo(participantInfo);
    }
    return (
        <div className="main flex-1 flex flex-col">
            <div className="hidden lg:block heading flex-2">
                <h1 className="text-3xl text-gray-700 mb-4">Chat</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-1 flex h-full">
                <div className=" hidden lg:flex w-1/3 flex-col pr-6">
                    <SearchBar onChange={ value => setSearchQuery(value) } />
                    <div className="flex-1 h-full overflow-auto px-2">
                        { filteredConversations.length > 0 ? (
                            filteredConversations.map((convo) => (
                                <Conversation
                                    key={ convo.id }
                                    name={ convo.participantInfo?.name }
                                    convoId={ convo.id }
                                    date={ convo.messages?.timestamp ?? '' }
                                    unread={ convo.unreadMessageCount ?? null }
                                    onClick={ () => handleConversationClick(convo.id, convo.participantInfo) }
                                />
                            ))
                        ) : (
                            <p>No conversation.</p>
                        ) }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ChatArea
                    selectedConversationId={ selectedConversationId }
                    selectedGroupInfo={ selectedParticipantInfo }
                />
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

this is the ChatArea component:

```
import { MessageListComponent } from '../MessageList'

export function ChatArea({ selectedConversationId, selectedGroupInfo }) {
    if (!selectedConversationId)
    {
        return (
            <div className='mt-16 w-2/3 flex justify-center'>
                <p className='italic'>Choice a conversation.</p>
            </div>
        )
    };
    return (
        <MessageListComponent
            className={ selectedConversationId !== null ? "" : "hidden" }
            conversationId={ selectedConversationId }
            participantInfo={ selectedGroupInfo }
        />
    );
}
```

this is MessageList component:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { messageAPIs } from '../../apis/messageAPI';
import { showMessage } from '../../utils/messageNoti';
import './index.css';
import { usePubNub } from "../../context/PubNubContext";
import {
    addListeners, subscribeToChannels, publishMessage, unsubscribeAll,
} from '../../SDKs/Pubnub';
import { MessageListHeader } from './MessageListHeader';
import { MessageDisplay } from './MessageDisplay';
import { MessageInputForm } from './MessageInputForm';


export const MessageListComponent = ({ conversationId, className, participantInfo }) => {
    const pn = usePubNub();
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const [ messages, setMessages ] = useState([]);
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null);
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
    const [ messageInput, setMessageInput ] = useState("");
    const endOfMessagesRef = useRef(null);

    const handleNewMessage = useCallback((envelope) => {
        setMessages(prevMessages => [ ...prevMessages, envelope.message ]);
        
    }, []);
    const handlePresence = useCallback((e) => {
        const { action, uuid, occupancy, channel } = e;
        switch (action)
        {
            case 'join':
                console.log(`User ${ uuid } joined channel ${ channel }`);
                break;
            case 'leave':
                console.log(`User ${ uuid } left channel ${ channel }`);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        addListeners(pn, {
            message: handleNewMessage,
            presence: handlePresence
        });
        subscribeToChannels(pn, [ conversationId ]);
        return () => {
            pn.removeListener({
                message: handleNewMessage,
                presence: handlePresence
            });
            unsubscribeAll(pn);
        };
    }, [ conversationId, pn ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getMessages = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try
            {
                const fetchedMessages = await messageAPIs.getMessagesInConver(conversationId);
                setMessages(fetchedMessages.data.messages);
            } catch (error)
            {
                setError(error);
            } finally
            {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };
        getMessages();
    }, [ conversationId ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        endOfMessagesRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }, [ messages ]);

    const sendMessage = async (content) => {
        try
        {
            const messageData = {
                senderUserId: user.id,
                content,
                messageType: 'text',
            };
            if (Array.isArray(participantInfo.participants))
            {
                messageData.recipientUserId = participantInfo.participants.map(p => p.user.id);
            } else
            {
                messageData.recipientUserId = participantInfo?.id;
            }
            const responseData = await messageAPIs.sendMessageToConvo(messageData);
            if (responseData.status !== 201)
            {
                throw new Error('Send error.');
            }
            publishMessage(pn, conversationId, responseData.data.message);
        } catch (error)
        {
            showMessage('Send error.', 'error');
        }
    };

    const handleSendMessage = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (messageInput.trim())
        {
            await sendMessage(messageInput);
            setMessageInput("");
        }
    };    

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error loading: { error.message }</p>;

    return (
        <>
            <div className={ `flex-1 flex flex-col ${ className } relative` }>
                <MessageListHeader participantInfo={ participantInfo } onVideoCall={ handleVideoCall } />
                <MessageDisplay messages={ messages } user={ user } participantInfo={ participantInfo } endOfMessagesRef={ endOfMessagesRef } />
                <MessageInputForm messageInput={ messageInput } setMessageInput={ setMessageInput } handleSendMessage={ handleSendMessage } />
            </div>            
        </>
    );
}
```

I don't know how to implement the function of counting unread messages to display on the UI in realtime, please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling an api when user subscribes to the chat then send an extra parameter **read** boolean. You can then count based on that boolean how many chats are unread. If you are not making an api call then I suggest you do and get this data from the backend instead of computing it on the frontend side.